Confusion about training and prediction images' shape
I'm doing semantic segmentation task in Keras - classifying trees from background. My images are initially of shape (256, 256, 3). However, I want to resize them to (128, 128) to speed up the training. I'm also taking part in a competition and my output file should be of shape (num_images, 256, 256) but my model can work only with (128, 128) images now and when I try to predict on (256, 256) images I get this error:
  ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model_4" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 128, 128, 1), found shape=(None, 256, 256, 1)

I'm using Unet model:
  inputs = Input((128, 128, 1))

  s = Lambda(lambda x: x / 255) (inputs)

  c1 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (s)
  c1 = Dropout(0.1) (c1)
  c1 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c1)
  p1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c1)

  c2 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (p1)
  c2 = Dropout(0.1) (c2)
  c2 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c2)
  p2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c2)

  ...

  u9 = Conv2DTranspose(16, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c8)
  u9 = concatenate([u9, c1], axis=3)
  c9 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (u9)
  c9 = Dropout(0.1) (c9)
  c9 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c9)

  outputs = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid') (c9)

  model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])
  model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')

Is there a way to train model on images of smaller sizes and still be able to make predictions on larger images? Can somebody please give a hint on how to solve this? Thanks in advance.
EDIT:
this is the function for getting data:
def get_data(a, path, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CHANNELS, t):
  out = np.zeros((len(a), IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CHANNELS), 
  dtype=t)
  for i, image_id in enumerate(a):
    path_image = path + image_id
    image = np.array(Image.open(path_image).convert('L'))
    image = resize(image, (IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH), mode='constant', 
    preserve_range=True)
    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=-1)
  out[i] = image
  return out


Your images are colored that's why your image shape is (256, 256, 3) for each base color, 'Red', 'Green', and 'Blue' (RGB) there is a value for the pixel in the 256x256 matrix.
images of the (128, 128) are gray-colored images. There are several techniques to convert color images into gray.
I suggest you install the OpenCV library (pip install opencv-python).
import cv2 as cv

resized_image = cv.resize(your_image, (128, 128))
resized_gray_image = cv.cvtColor(resized_image, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)


I added how I read the data and in that function I convert images to grayscale so their 3d  dimension is 1
